# Windows takes long to access other PCs over network

Tags: windows, networking, performance, authentication

why does windows (from xp to 7) take so long to access other machines over network?

In detail: if I do Start -> run -> \machineinLocalNet\c$ oder \machineinLocalNet\share it always takes long to bring up the credentials dialog.

I ask this, because I never saw it any other way in every network I was woking in. Even if the machines are in the same active directory domain.

I assume there is some authentication process running, but there has to be something that can be done about it.

Regards,
Uwe

Comment: You may get better responses if you provide additional information about your physical topology (speeds/types of NICs, cables, switches), as well as DNS details, number of hosts, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The PC is probably having problems resolving the IP address from the machine name. If you are on a domain, check in the network settings that the Primary DNS is set to the IP address of your domain controller. If you are on a workgroup, check that WINS is properly configured.

Also check that no firewalls are blocking windows networking protocols.

Comment: A ping on the machine name is no problem at all. The DNS and the DC are in the same network.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a master browser issue. Here are some links:

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q188001
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;288801

Hope this helps.