# Fileshares hang when Vista talks to 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-vista, network-share

So my box is running Vista Business all patched up nice.  The dev server is on win2003.  What sometimes happens is that I'll click on a file, usually an image, and then get nothing more from the box.  Nobody can access the fileshares, but it serves up webpages and I can remote in OK.  Nothing in the logs, long timeout before an error is reported.

So I imagine the file protocol is crashing, and that's probably due to differences in security policy in the two OSs, but I've had no luck finding anything so far.

We've jsut put two new staff on Vista machines and this is getting to be less of an inconveniance and more of a problem.

So, seen this behaviour before?

Answer (score 1):

This may be related to a  master browser issue, the following question may be related to your problem:

[Windows takes long to access other PCs over network](https://serverfault.com/questions/44976/windows-takes-long-to-access-other-pcs-over-network/48434#48434)

Hope this helps.